# How would I add a short time delay to this countup script? (so that it starts to count up when the user actually sees it, maybe a 4-5 second delay)

Tags: javascript

I have a counter section on my page that animates the numbers increasing on page load, however, the section is just below the fold so I'd like to add a short delay to make it more likely for a user to see it as they begin to scroll, perhaps a 4-5 second delay. I'm not sure how to include it in this particular script.

JS:

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

$({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
countNum: countTo
},

{

duration: 8000,
easing:'linear',
step: function() {
  $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
},
complete: function() {
  $this.text(this.countNum);
  //alert('finished');
}


});  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stats">
<div class="counter" data-count="8">0</div>
<p>YEARS' EXPERIENCE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try inserting `.delay(5000)` right before `.animate(...)`. Alternatively, wrap the code in `setTimeout(function() { /* code here */ }, 5000);`

Comment: Tried the first, worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just wait for the user to scroll down by listening to the `scroll` event?